# Chart binding with database problem cause Date format

Tags: c#, date, charts

I'm trying to bind chart to database. Database contains more columns (id,sum , date , categoryID, and many more. My problem is, im not able to bind chart with sum and date. Sum should be on Y axes and date should be on X axes. I beginner in C# so probably im doing something wrong there. Every time when I click button there is a chart but with wrong values.

```
string commandString = "select sum, date from wallettbl order by date";
cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con); 
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dataReader;
dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {             
         this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dataReader["sum"], dataReader["date"]); 
         this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
       }

        con.Close();
```

I expected to have chart with my data from database, and every time when I click button it will be realoaded, again not added to the current one.

Comment: What is the error? Is it by chance that you are passing a DateTime where chart would expect say an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Dávid.

Did you try to put date on the first parameter?

Ex:

```
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dataReader["date"], dataReader["sum"]);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh...I was so deep into programing i didnt saw it.Thank you.